# Code seems out-of-scope, How to fix? (Simple Queue-ADT program)

Tags: java, interface, queue, adt, abstract-data-type

Im not sure how to exactly explain this problem, but Im pretty sure Im making a very simple mistake that can be corrected quite quickly.
Also, I thought it would be more convenient if this was shown off as a screenshot. The first two tabs are my interface and error catching classes.

[image]

As you can see, the code for methods to use in my Queue ADT seems to be out of scope. So I can move on and complete this bit of coursework, can someone explain to me why it is out of scope?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Declare those variables as instance variables, not local variables of the `main` method .

Comment: Please post your code in the question as text, not a linked image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare those variables in `main` method, so only `main` local scope know them. Move the declaration to class level

```
public class QueueProgram {
    private static int queuesize = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Note I declared `queuesize` as `static` since the `main` uses it. Another option is to create `getters` and `setters` and call them with an instance of `QueueProgram`

```
public class QueueProgram {
    private int queuesize = 10;

    public int getQueuesize() {
        return queuesize;
    }

    public void setQueuesize(int size) {
        queuesize = size;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueueProgram program = new QueueProgram();
        program.getQueuesize(); // return 10;
        program.setQueuesize(5);
        program.getQueuesize(); // now it is 5;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy :3